# Node server is running but not able to run on browser and port is undefined

Tags: node.js, port

I am new to Node JS. I got this problem on my first app. Node server is running. But in console it is saying port undefined and on browser it is saying refused to connect.

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req,res) =>{
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type','text/plain');
    res.end('Hello world');
});
server.listen((port,hostname) => {
console.log('server started on port: '+port);
});
```

I have tried http://127.0.0.1:3000/ and http://localhost:3000/. But didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of `http.listen()` is:

> server.listen(port, callback);

But but what you are doing is

> server.listen(callback)

As you only passed a arrow function in `http.listen()` as a result port is unknown.

So what you have to do is:

```
server.listen(port, (err) => {
   console.log('server started on port: '+port);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to specify a hostname when calling `listen`. Also, the port should be the 1st parameter, the callback should be the 2nd.
Working example:

```
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req,res) =>{
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type','text/plain');
    res.end('Hello world');
});

server.listen(port, (err) => {
    // err handling
    console.log('server started on port: '+port);
});
```

Now going to `localhost:3000` on your browser will yield your wanted result.